# SvelteKit - /routes/a/+page.server.ts fetch('/b/') url confusion, version @sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.512

Tags: sveltekit

When I try to fetch('/b/') within the load function of **/routes/a/+page.server.ts** it refuses to accept local URL references.

Instead of being able to do

```
/b/
```

I have to use url:

```
http://localhost:3000/b/
```

Because the fetch() call refuses to accept the url (**error:  "Failed to parse URL"**). I'm trying to consume my own api to reuse code. I thought SvelteKit fetch was supposed to support these local routes for api calls?

The example in documentation: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing

Shows +page.svelte calling url '/api/add/' from fetch(), but not from within +page.server.ts - is there some reason they would not allow the same convention?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SvelteKit developers got back to me and indicated that there are two choices of fetch(url) function.

```js
// /src/routes/test/[param0]/[param1]/+page.server.ts
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ params }) => {
   // ERROR: this will fail with URL parsing
   let fetchResult = fetch('/api/target/');
}
```

SvelteKit aware fetch passed as load function parameter:

```js
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ params, fetch }) => {
   // NOTE: fetch was passed in as a parameter to this function
   let fetchResult = fetch('/api/target/');
}
```

Confusing!

Answer (score 0):

When I have an internal API route I want to hit within my sveltekit application, I structure it as so:

```
├src
|├routes
||├api
|||├example
||||├+server.js
```

Now, elsewhere in the app, you can hit the route like so using the fetch api:

```
let res = await fetch("/api/example")
```

refer to this section of the SvelteKit docs for a better understanding:
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing

Comment: the question is specific to the load() function of a +page.server.ts /+page.server.js file. The fetch("/api/example") there refuses the url format and requires you to append http://localhost/ in front.

Comment: This is not the case in my experience. Per the docs (in reference to fetch):
"it can make relative requests on the server (ordinarily, fetch requires a URL with an origin when used in a server context)"
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load

What's going on inside of your /b directory?

Comment: the /b/ works fine if I use a URL of http://localhost/b/ - but the fetch('/b/') refuses with exception on URL. Again, this is a server-side page, I don't know if this is a bug or a documentation issue, but looking for someone to confirm the problem at least before I go open an issue with the SvelteKit developers.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with sveltekit--without knowing what you're trying to do within the /b/ route (GET, POST request?) I don't think we can properly diagnose your issue.

Are you trying to receive data from /b/ ? Is it a page you're trying to receive in the +page.server.js for some reason? I'm unsure what you're trying to accomplish. All I can tell based on your description is that it seems like there's a misuse of what SvelteKit considers an internal API route.

Comment: You truly keep ignoring that +page.ts isn't the same as +page.server.ts - try it yourself. fetch("/api/example") throws an error: "Failed to parse URL"